# Read vector from file

Tags: c++, r, vector, rcpp

I have a large vector of length 650 million. I wish to store this vector on disk (5 GB), then load the entire vector into memory so that various functions can quickly access its elements.

Here is my attempt to do this in Rcpp on a smaller scale. The following code simply causes my R session to crash, with no error messages. What am I doing wrong?

R code:

```r
output_file = file(description="test.bin",open="a+b")
writeBin(runif(10), output_file,size=8)
close(output_file)
```

Rcpp code:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace Rcpp;

std::vector<double> read_vector_from_file(std::string filename)
{
  std::vector<char> buffer{};
  std::ifstream ifs(filename, std::ios::in | std::ifstream::binary);
  std::istreambuf_iterator<char> iter(ifs);
  std::istreambuf_iterator<char> end{};
  std::copy(iter, end, std::back_inserter(buffer));
  std::vector<double> newVector(buffer.size() / sizeof(double));
  memcpy(&newVector[0], &buffer[0], buffer.size());
  return newVector;
}

std::vector<double> LT = read_vector_from_file("test.bin");

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double Rcpp_test() {
  return LT[3];
}
```

Comment: By my rough calculation that's 56 bytes * 36400000000 = ~36Gb in RAM if your vector is filled with e.g. double. Do you have enough RAM?

Comment: First off, why the detour via a `char` buffer?

Comment: Your `read_…` code works, even though it’s very memory inefficient. The issue is elsewhere. I suspect it’s due to your static initialisation of `LT`. Generally, static initialisation inside libraries is fraught with difficulties, you should only use it when you understand exactly what order it’s evaluated in. For Rcpp, I have no clue. At any rate, removing the static initialisation of `LT` fixes your crash. Instead, you can move this code into a function and return it to R wrapped into an `Rcpp::XPtr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over the years I have implemented something like the above a few times for quick and dirty data story.  *These days I no longer recommend it* as we have *fabulous* packages such as [fst](https://cloud.r-project.org/package=fst) and [qs](https://cloud.r-project.org/package=qs) who do this better, with parallelisation, and compression, and other whistles.

But as you asked, an answer follows. I have found the C API for files to be simpler, and closer to what you do in R.  So here we just open, and read 10 items of size 8 (for `double`) as that is what we know you wrote. I have at time generalized that and written two `int` values for an `enum` of types as well as numbers.

##### Code

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector Rcpp_test(std::string filename, size_t size) {
    Rcpp::NumericVector v(size);
    FILE *in = fopen(filename.c_str(), "rb");
    if (in == nullptr) Rcpp::stop("Cannot open file", filename);
    auto nr = fread(&v[0], sizeof(double), size, in);
    if (nr != size) Rcpp::stop("Bad payload");
    Rcpp::Rcout << nr << std::endl;
    fclose(in);
    return v;
}

/*** R
set.seed(123)
rv <- runif(10)
filename <- "test.bin"
if (!file.exists(filename)) {
  output_file <- file(description="test.bin",open="a+b")
  writeBin(rv, output_file, size=8)
  close(output_file)
}
nv <- Rcpp_test(filename, 10)
data.frame(rv, nv)
all.equal(rv,nv)
*/
```

##### Output

The code is a slight generalization by fixing the seed and comparing written and read data.

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp("answer.cpp")

> set.seed(123)

> rv <- runif(10)

> filename <- "test.bin"

> if (!file.exists(filename)) {
+   output_file <- file(description="test.bin",open="a+b")
+   writeBin(rv, output_file, size=8)
+   close(output_file .... [TRUNCATED] 

> nv <- Rcpp_test(filename, 10)
10

> data.frame(rv, nv)
          rv        nv
1  0.2875775 0.2875775
2  0.7883051 0.7883051
3  0.4089769 0.4089769
4  0.8830174 0.8830174
5  0.9404673 0.9404673
6  0.0455565 0.0455565
7  0.5281055 0.5281055
8  0.8924190 0.8924190
9  0.5514350 0.5514350
10 0.4566147 0.4566147

> all.equal(rv,nv)
[1] TRUE
>
```

Comment: I dunno about “simpler” — your C code only works with fixed-size data. Reading dynamically-sized data efficiently immediately becomes much harder in C because you’re left performing manual resizing. The best you can do is to seek to the end and estimate the data size from the offset, but that’s brittle.

Comment: a) That is a trivial fix. Just pass it in the signature or read from the file info. b) Goal was a _working_ .  Actually, it already takes a size argument and checks.  As for use case, we used something just like this for years to dump and load R vectors which are fixed (known) size.  And as I said, today I would just use `fst` which is smarter _and_ faster.  My answer shows OP what a working version of his approach looks like.  No more, but also no less.  Feel free to add one with iostream / filestream use.

Comment: Like I said, I disagree that it’s trivial (to do efficiently *and* robustly). You’re left either relying on the fact that the file doesn’t change while you’re reading it, or you need to resize the vector while reading into it. The whole point of C++ file IO is that it frees the user of such concerns. — Furthermore, OP’s file reading code *already works*. The issue is elsewhere (I suspect static initialisation order).

Comment: The initial approach by OP is less general than mine, and crashes.  Mine sets out to do what he wants and works. That's good enough a winning comparison for me so I leave it here.  You may have read the opening paragraph of my answer where I suggest more powerfull and general alternatives _but in the requested context of reading one binary blob_ I still find C easier.  I note that you disagreed and exmplained yourself, so we can probably conclude this debated soon enough.

Comment: Thank you very much for your example and your suggested alternatives.

Comment: @WeiHong My pleasure, and belated welcome to StackOverflow too.  You can 'acknowledge' the answer as useful by upvoting it (click on the 'up' triangle) as well as accepting it (click on the 'tick' mark).  Accepting it gives you karma points too, you need a minimum of ten points before you can accept an answer.